# Currently, is it possible to enter the Kaliningrad Region via Poland and exit via Lithuania?

Tags: russia, poland, lithuania, kaliningrad

This has nothing to do with visas. Taking into account the current war, are there any blockades from Russian, Polish and Lithuanian authorities regarding entrance to the Kaliningrad Region?

I would enter through Poland (Goldap-Gusiew crossing) and exit through Lithuania (Chernyshevskoye crossing), possibly on the same day. I am neither Russian nor Ukrainian.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Polish border website](https://granica.gov.pl/przejscia.php?v=en), this particular crossing is temporarily closed. Other locations appear to be open.

Whether that notice is up to date I cannot say.

> NOTICE
>
> Border traffic is temporarily suspended at the following road border crossing points:
>
> - Border with Russia - Gronowo, Gołdap

Kybartai appears to be open, you can at least make [reservations](https://www.lithuanianborder.eu/yphis/index.action) to cross the border there.